# Differentiate between plugin HTTP requests and JavaScript HTTP requests

Tags: flash, plugins, xul, xulrunner

I am writing a XUL application which records all the network communication happening inside a browser instance created using `<browser>` tag.

I can use http-on-modify-request to track all the requests being made and modify headers accordingly but I can not differentiate which request is made by a plugin like Flash or if it's been made by JavaScript.

Is there a way I can differentiate such requests?

Answer (score 1):

Alert, nasty hack incoming!

You definitely can't differentiate the requests for Flash vs Javascript, as they actually use the same Mozilla platform APIs.

However, there's nothing stopping you *making* the non-Flash request look different when examined in an `http-on-modify-request` implementation -- you need to do something to make all those non-Flash requets look different.

The easiest way I can think of is to add (and then strip off inside your `http-on-modify-request` handler) a QueryString parameter.

So basically, just add something like `?___NONFLASH__=897123487` or `&___NONFLASH__=897123487` to each request URI. (where you randomly generate the token `897123487` at initialisation so that it can't be guessed by JavaScript/Flash trying to 'escape' from this "sandbox").

You'd need to affect the following in browser's `content.contentDocument`:

- links - alter their `href` attributes
- forms - alter their `action` attributes
- `window.XMLHttpRequest` - replace this with a version of your own making (make sure you replace it before any client-script runs!)

That just leaves client script-initiated `window`-level navigation (e.g: `window.location.href` changes). You could use either an `NSIObserver` or an `NSIProgressListener` to watch for the URL changing/re-loading.

**edit:** all of this assumes that the flash content isn't using a Flash<-->JavaScript bridge and doing all the requests on the JavaScript side (unlikely! -- but possible).